# Burning Lubuntu to Dell PC

Tags: linux, macos, iso-image, dvd-burning, dell-dimension

I have an old Dell PC Dimension 8200 that I'm trying to install Lubuntu on. I'm burning the ISO image on a Mac 10.6 using Disk Utility, but when I try to boot it on the Dell, it doesn't recognize the disc. I have an old version of Ubuntu that works fine. My experimentation has led me to a few questions:

- When downloading an ISO on a Mac to go on a PC, do I select the Mac or PC version of the ISO?
- After Disk Utility says "The disk has been burned successfully burned", when I reinsert it into my Mac, I get an error saying "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer." Then it ejects it. Why might that be?
- Are there any other steps I might be missing?

I'd be happy to provide more information, I'm just not really sure where to begin right now.

UPDATE: So I booted a lubuntu install CD in another PC and it worked fine. The Dell seems to accept the Ubuntu 10.04 install CD fine but doesn't know what to do with Lubuntu 14.04. Weird. If anyone has the answer why I'd love to know.

Comment: Maybe try a slower write speed? Have you verified that the md5sum of the ISO you've downloaded matches the original one? And you should be picking the PC version of the ISO if you're installing on the Dell.

Comment: Note, when I go in Disk Utility to "Open Disk Image" and choose the ISO, it loads in the sidebar but a message pops up that reads "unable to attach 'lubuntu.iso' (no mountable file systems)".

Comment: Where are you downloading the lubuntu iso from and which are you downloading? And yes you would pick the PC version (with correct 32/64 bit) - pick the version of the machine you're intending to install it on, not the one your burning the cd from.

Comment: And, as an alternate option, does your Dell support booting from USB devices? If so, grab the appropriate lubuntu iso then use [unetbootin for os x](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to write it to the thumb drive. See if the Dell boots from that. You may have to ensure the thumb drive has an msdos mbr and is formatted as fat32 first.

Comment: Thanks @JasonC, but I initially tried that and found that the BIOS has no option to boot from USB. Upvote for the thumb drive formatting info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out the problem was two-fold:

- I wasn't mounting the ISO in Disk Utility before burning it (this one
  was tricky)
- The Dell tower I was using has a CD-ROM drive, not DVD

Answer (score 1):

For running burned disc on your Dell  machine you should download Ubuntu 32 bit, not mac.